# Draw sine wave with increasing frequency processing

Tags: math, processing, frequency

I have the following code that draws a sine wave. 
see my code below:

```cpp
float x, y;
float prevX=0.0, prevY=0.0;
int numOfWaves = 6;
float angle = 0;

void setup()
{
  size(360, 360);
  background(0);
  smooth();
  stroke(255);
}

void draw()
{
  translate(0, height/2);
  scale(1, -1);

  for(int count=0; count < 360; ++count){
    x = count;

    angle = radians(count);
    y = sin(angle*(numOfWaves/2.0));

    y = map(y,-1,1,-height/2,height/2);

    line(prevX, prevY, x, y);

    prevX = x;
    prevY = y;
  }

  prevX = prevY = 0.0;
}
```

But I would like the frequency of the sine to increase over distance. 
this is the current sine wave I get:

[image]

But I want to make it look like this:
[image]

How would I do this?

Comment: In that last graphic, the frequency *decreases* as you move from left to right, and the wavelength increases. Is that what you want, or do you want the frequency to increase to the right, or is something else happening beyond one of the ends of your graphic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know how to plot `sin(2*π*f*t)`.

A "chirp" will have a frequency that is itself a function of time:

```
y(t) = A*sin(2*π*f(t)*t)
```

Where `f(t)` can be linear, quadratic, or anything else you choose.

Comment: hey thanks for the answer! but i really know very little about math :( could u maybe give a code example on how to implement this?

Comment: Here's something that will help: https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/chirp.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com.  You have to learn something about the math.

Comment: Your plot is x - and y-coordinates.  Think of them as independent and dependent variables.  The names don't matter.  I think about x as "time" and y as "amplitude".  Write a loop over the time range (several cycles of your function).  Plug the time into the frequency versus time and amplitude versus time functions that I gave you and plot the result.